# Center text over image on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

The text will sometimes spill over the "label" for the sections with various browser sizes. [Here](http://dev.mrmerch.net) is the link for the site.

And here is an excerpt from the code -

HTML -

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="imgwrap">
                <div class="service smooth">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrmerch.com/images/Apparel.svg" class="img-responsive" alt="Printed merchandise"><p class="imgdescription">Sample image description.</p>                        
                </div>
                </div>
                <h4>Printed Apparel</h4>
            </div>
```

CSS for hover -

```
.imgdescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 7%;
  right: 7%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
}

.imgwrap:hover img{
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transform:scale(.95);
    opacity: .05;
}

.imgwrap:hover .imgdescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #000;
  font-family: interstate-light,Helvetica, highway_gothic_wideregular, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[Here is an example of what I'm seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p63hy.png)

Comment: yes, the problem is in small devices

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved by Bootstrap, just for every image and text on hover, give
`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <!--Put image and it's description-->
    </div>
  </div>`
This should help, also give it styling `text-align:center`, so to align it at center for small devices

Comment: I appreciate the help! I tried that, but I'm still encountering the issue. I added a link to the original post that shows what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your text being in position: absolute doesn't push the content below it when it appears. Instead of its visibility, you should change the display value on it, change to position to relative, and make the image position: absolute instead. When you make the text appear, it should post the content below it then.

Here is a rough example:

```
.service {min-height: 100px; position: relative;}
.imgwrap .img {position: absolute; top: 0;}
.service p {display: none;}

.imgwrap:hover img{
  position: absolute;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transform:scale(.95);
    opacity: .05;
}

.imgwrap:hover .imgdescription {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: display .5s ease-in;
  transition: display .5s ease-out;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #000;
  font-family: interstate-light,Helvetica, highway_gothic_wideregular, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

You can see it live there:
https://jsfiddle.net/yjzpw0pa/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm actually not trying to get the text below the image - I just want it to center over the image, whereas now it's bleeding over the service description.

Comment: You text is too long for that in a small screen though. Are you looking at simply resizing the text on small screen?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  .imgdescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 7%;
  right: 7%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
}

.imgwrap:hover img{
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transform:scale(.95);
    opacity: .05;
}

.imgwrap:hover .imgdescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #000;
  font-family: interstate-light,Helvetica, highway_gothic_wideregular, Arial, sans-serif;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

The text will sometimes spill over the "label" for the sections with various browser sizes. Here is the link for the site.

And here is an excerpt from the code -

HTML -
<div style="width:90%;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="imgwrap">
                <div class="service smooth">
                    <img style="margin: 0 auto" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrmerch.com/images/Apparel.svg" class="img-responsive" alt="Printed merchandise">
                  
          <p style="width:98%;text-align:center" class="imgdescription">We source a wide variety of high-quality blanks and print using a combination of modern machinery and human perfectionism.</p>                      
                </div>
                </div>
                <h4>Printed Apparel</h4>
            </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this out now, this is what u want, u can adjust the width of text on hover by changing width.